# Does 'pagination' refer to page numbers only or line numbers as well?

Tags: paper-submission, terminology, formatting

With reference to manuscripts, does 'ensuring pagination' only mean that each page is numbered, or does it mean that lines are numbered as well? Is there an equivalent word/phrase for numbering lines?

The question is about the general use of the term, rather than a journal/publisher specific requirement.

Comment: It is strange that the referee cares about pagination. The article will change a lot after copy editing into the journal format.

Comment: @VladimirF- this is not a referee comment (yet atleast), rather a general instruction, i.e. 'Please ensure that your manuscript is paginated, as this will help both editors and reviewers to process it promptly.'

Comment: Do you have a style guide you're following? This should normally explain about page and line numbering requirements. Without a style guide, you need to see how documents are commonly formatted.

Comment: @StuartF- This instruction is from the style guide, leaving me a bit confused. I've seen other submission documents since, and their formats seem to be in line with the answers below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, proper, and precise usage:

- ***Pagination*** (aka ***page breaking***) refers only to the process of segregating content across *pages*.
- ***Line breaking*** is a similar process of segregating content except across *lines*.

In both cases, the quality of the solutions to the problems is measured by computational efficiency and design aesthetic.

Both terms are orthogonal to numbering, referring to where to place breaks, not whether to number the resulting pages or lines.

### References

- [*Breaking Paragraphs into Lines*](http://www.eprg.org/G53DOC/pdfs/knuth-plass-breaking.pdf), Donald E. Knuth and Michael F. Plass, 1981
- [*Optimal Pagination Techniques for Automatic Typesetting Systems*](https://tug.org/docs/plass/plass-thesis.pdf), Michael F Plass, 1981

Comment: Thanks, the references are useful!

Answer (score 11):

The term "pagination" refers to the process of separating content into distinct pages.  Poor pagination occurs when content is cut-off in a strange way across pages ---e.g., the heading for a new section occurs on the last line of a page, a figure and its label are separated onto distinct pages, etc.  If a referee is criticising your pagination it probably means that you have a part of your manuscript where you have something cut-off over pages in a way that looks strange.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, is there no relation between pagination and actually numbering the pages?

Comment: Not to my knowledge --- as I understand the term, page numbering is a separate issue.

Comment: Consider a book or thesis - you'd paginate a chapter by splitting it into pages suitably, but the page numbering would only come when the chapters are assembled into a whole.  This also applies to journal articles where each article starts at the top of a page; if articles can start partway through a page the journal will re-paginate. In practice they probably will anyway; some provide LaTeX classes that match the final pagination pretty well, though abstract books and proceedings of small conferences may use author-provided files as-is

Comment: In a comment the OP says "this will help both editors and reviewers to process it promptly.". That suggests  to me that they're talking about page numbering, since they would be used to refer to the locations that a comment is about. Poor pagination just makes the document slightly harder to read.